# SQL Server INSERT trigger how to get data of current row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I've never created a trigger before and I'm trying to read online but am a little confused.

I want to create a trigger on a table that on insert, it will grab some data from different columns and insert it into a few different other tables.

I'm not sure how to write the T-SQL to get the data from the columns..

```
insert into [othetTable] 
values ([col1 from row that was inserted], [col5 from row that was inserted])
```

What would the syntax be to get those values?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `inserted` virtual table that is available to triggers. Note that there could be multiple rows in this table - your trigger could be processing multiple inserts at once.

Therefore, you need to use something like the following syntax:

```
insert into othertable
select col1, col5
from inserted
```

This will insert a row into `othertable` for each inserted row.